# angularjs ui-router authorization before proceeding

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a angularjs ui-router situation where:

- User must be authorized before hitting any page
- If user is authorized and has no route, redirect to their homepage
- If user is authorized and has a route, redirect to route
- If user is authorized and has no route and no homepage, navigate to default page
- If user is not authorized and has route, redirect to login page and upon authorization redirect to that route

Its a tricky situation and I can't seem to nail it just right.  My current code does work but... it has to shows the 'login' page for a split second before navigating.  This happens because I have to kick off the `$stateChangeStart` somehow.

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ui.router']);

// handle default states based on authentication,
// default properties set in user profile, or
// or just redirect to 'apps' page
var authd = false, 
    defaultDashboard = undefined,
    defaultFn = function($injector){
        // required to get location since loaded before app
        var $location = $injector.get('$location');

        // if the user has a default dashboard, navigate to that
        if(defaultDashboard){
            $location.path('workspace/' + defaultDashboard);
        } else if(authd) {
            // if the user is auth'd but doesn't have url
            $location.path('home');
        } else {
            // if we aren't auth'd yet
            $location.path('login');
        }
    };

app.config(function ($urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $stateProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    app.stateProvider = $stateProvider;

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector){
        defaultFn($injector);
    });
});

app.run(function ($rootScope, $q, $location, $state, $stateParams, $injector, security) {

    var deregister = $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function () {

        // authorize is a AJAX request to pass session token and return profile for user
        security.authorize().success(function(d){

            // set some local flags for defaultFn
            authd = true;
            defaultDashboard = d.defaultDashboard;

            // de-register the start event after login to prevent further calls
            deregister();

            // switch to default view after login
            if($location.$$url === "/login" || 
                    $location.$$url === "/"){
                defaultFn($injector);
            }

        }).error(function(){
            $location.path('login');
        });
    });
});
```

I'm using a inceptor to handle 401s like:

```
var module = angular.module('security.interceptor', []);

// This http interceptor listens for authentication failures
module.factory('securityInterceptor', function($injector, $location) {
    return function(promise) {

        // Intercept failed requests
        return promise.then(null, function(originalResponse) {
            if(originalResponse.status === 401) {
                $location.path('/login');
            }

            return promise;
        });
    };
});

// We have to add the interceptor to the queue as a string because the 
// interceptor depends upon service instances that are not available in the config block.
module.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push('securityInterceptor');
});
```

anyone had any similar cases and found a better solution?

Comment: I'm not sure it's a very good solution to put your rerouting in the .run function. Why do you set $location.path first and then subsequently wait for .run to fire it up ? Why don't you use $state.go() ? http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state . And finally, how and where do you store the session data? Local Storage? Something else?

Comment: @Bonatoc - its a server request, its a user profile.  regarding the run, can you give a little more details?

Comment: Did you take this tutorial as a basis for your script, by any chance? http://arthur.gonigberg.com/2013/06/29/angularjs-role-based-auth/ . And yes, my bad, .run apparently is the place to perform auth checking, as it is fired right after .config.

Comment: @Bonatoc ya something similar, i added the inceptor im using

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Heres my solution I came up with:

```
app.config(function ($urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $stateProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    // placeholder
    $stateProvider.state('welcome', {
        url: '/'
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('404');
});

app.run(function ($rootScope, $q, $location, $state, $stateParams, security, $urlRouter) {

    var deregister = $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (event) {
        // stop the change!
        event.preventDefault();

        security.authorize().success(function(d){
            // if we don't have a previous url
            if($location.$$url === "/" || $location.$$url === "/login"){

                // If user has a preset home
                if(d.defaultDashboard){
                    $location.path('workspace/' + d.defaultDashboard);
                } else {
                    $location.path('welcome');
                }
            } else {
                // if we do, then continue
                $urlRouter.sync();
            }
        }).error(function(){
            // redirect to home
            $location.path('login');
        });

        // deregister the listener
        deregister();
    });

});
```

Essentially, creating a empty route for an empty route solved my problem.  Interesting.